# MySQL Database Charset

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have just migrated a MySQL database to a new server using mysqldump. The charset of database is normally UTF-8 and everything was working fine on the old server but when we switched over to new one, the special characters started not to show properly. The only difference I can see between two servers is that the default charset of new server is set to latin1 in my.cnf whereas this was not the case on old server.

I have tried to replace all these special characters using interconnect/it's tool but that did not work.

What needs to be done to get this fixed? What should one pay attention to in such a situation? Charsets of database, table?

Comment: Can you not change the charset in the new server to UTF-8? The data in the DB is physically stored different based on these settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708958/differences-between-utf8-and-latin1

Comment: It's already set to utf8 for this specific database indeed. I've confirmed that database/table charsets are looking identical on both servers.

Comment: What versions of mysql and linux systems are we dealing w/ here?

Comment: Both are 5.5.28. (Server version: 5.5.28-log)

Comment: This article is long but may help you in solving this particular issue: https://www.bluebox.net/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell. I've had this problem happen to me in the past as well and I seem to recall getting the tables & DB set in UTF-8 prior, and then re-importing my mysqldumps into them once they were set appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by replacing all special characters - those do not show up properly - with their original ones. (Thanks to interconnect/it's Search & Replace Tool) The important thing to pay attention at that point was to replace the charset of all these replaced items with utf8 as well. I was missing that part and when the items were replaced, they still were not showing up properly since the correct charset was not set.